# jQuery move href to another link

Tags: jquery

When an option in the ul is clicked, I want to move its href to the "Go button" so when this is clicked you will go to that page

I've done a quick fiddle demo but I'm struggling to get the chosen href into the go button

http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8z/1/

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.button').attr('href','');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `href` variable you just created as the buttons `href`:

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('.button').attr('href', href);
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8z/2/)

Comment: Bah, I thought I tried this but I must of put apostrophes around href!
Thanks